# pod install for imglyKit taking too long

Tags: cocoapods, pod-install, imglykit

i took a pull from the main branch and apparently, there were some new packages so i run npm i and then **pod install** which is installing pods at a usual speed until it comes to **Installing imglyKit (11.8.0)**. i believe that it's stuck here for more than 30 minutes by now. have anyone of you ever faced it? if so, how you got your way with it?

i tried cancelling it and then after deleting the pods file, re-run the command **pod install** and it gone stuck at the same pod again.